# jQuery adds background to div when using animate function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-cycle

I'm using jquery cycle plugin and jquery.
I animate the jquery cycle div when the height of the cycled div changes. The div below goes up or down according to the height.

The problem is that the div below gets a (white) background when it scrolls down. I'd like the div below to be transparent all the time. (in my example i'd like the content div to be transparent all the time)

here is the code to animate the cycled div

```
function onAfter(curr, next, opts, fwd) {
        var index = opts.currSlide;
        $('#prev,#prev2,#prev3,#prev4,#prev5')[index == 0 ? 'hide' : 'show']();
        $('#next,#next2,#next3,#next4,#next5')[index == opts.slideCount - 1 ? 'hide' : 'show']();
        //get the height of the current slide
        var $ht = $(this).height();
        //set the container's height to that of the current slide
        $(this).parent().animate({height: $ht});
    }

    $('.subheader').cycle({after: onAfter});
```

It's hard to explain, so i made a jsfiddle to show it: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ARd6h/2/)

Comment: I just added red background color to BODY (in the jsFiddle) and could not reproduce your results. (DIV with text remained transparent during animation -- I could see the red color of the BODY). Firefox 23.0.1 on 32Bit Linux. http://jsfiddle.net/ARd6h/3/

Comment: Either specific browser issue, or jsfiddle doesn't contain enough of the code/css/html to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @David-SkyMesh: Are you sure you're looking at the right thing? What you want to watch for is the vertical text "testing 1 2 3" being obscured (by any background, white or red) as the other text is sliding down. I see it on both Firefox 20 and Chrome 26 on 64-bit Linux. I've slowed it down to make it easier to see: http://jsfiddle.net/ARd6h/4/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm not sure how you get that from the question. In any case, I'm seeing the vertical text through the sliding div -- throughout the animation.

Comment: @David-SkyMesh that might be the problem, you just better explained it :)

Comment: ahh. scratch that. I am seeing what you're seeing @TJ

Comment: @David-SkyMesh: Ah, good, I was wondering what could have changed between Firefox 20 and 23 :-)

Comment: That explains it a bit better indeed... thx for looking at my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's happening is that `overflow: hidden` is being added to the `subheader` `div` as it is being animated. Doing that makes it clip the text.

If you animate it yourself and *only* set `height`, that should prevent the problem from happening.

Alternately, I was able to get around it using an `!important` style rule: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ARd6h/5/)

```
.subheader {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

That works because `!important` style rules have greater weight than inline styles (unless the inline style *also* has `!important`, in which case that would win).

Comment: Side note: I diagnosed this simply by opening Chrome's dev tools, highlighting the element, and watching what happened to its styles as it was being animated. I saw the `overflow: hidden` show up during the animation and go away when it was done animating, so I added `overflow: hidden` to it and saw that clipped the underlying text even *not* during animation, which told me what was causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot and also for adding how to diagnose the problem. (i usually use firebug which also shows what you described)